# PyGame : Use img.get_rect() for several images located in two lists and a unique width and height variable for them

Tags: python, pygame

I started creating a new game with PyGame in Python, I put all my sprite's images in two lists, so when I will be moving the sprite with the arrows, it will read the lists which has the sprite's images and it will give a reality effect (because we will see the sprite's legs moving).
The problem is that apparently **we can't use `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` for images in two lists** | ERROR : `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'x'`

Here is my code :

FILE : **main.py**

```
import os
from player import Player
import pygame
pygame.init()

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot The Villains")

persoDroit = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroitSansFeu.png'))
enemyRight = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_ennemiDroit.png'))
enemyLeft = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_ennemiGauche.png'))
backgroundGame = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'background.png'))

def affichage(health_Player, health_Enemy):
    global countSteps

    if player.countSteps >= 4: 
        player.countSteps = 0 

    if left:
        screen.blit(player.go_left[player.countSteps], player.rect.x) #Here I tried to call rect.x, in __init__ and move_left function, it doesn't work
        player.countSteps += 1 
    elif right:
        screen.blit(player.go_right[player.countSteps], (player.x,player.y))
        player.countSteps += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(persoDroit, (player.x,player.y))

player = Player()

palying = True 
while playing:

    screen.blit(backgroundGame, [0,0])

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        touche = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or touche[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            playing = False

    if touche[pygame.K_LEFT] and player.rect.x > 0:
        left = True
        right = False
        player.move_left() #I tried to call the function move_left in the Player() class
    elif touche[pygame.K_RIGHT] and player.x < screen.get_width()-64:
        left = False
        right = True
        player.x += player.speed
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        player.countSteps = 0

    display(player.health_Player, health_Enemy)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

SECOND FILE : **player.py**

```
import os
import pygame

current_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = os.path.join(current_path, 'images')

class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # On initialise 'pygame.sprite.Sprite'
        self.health_Player = 100
        self.reamaning_health_Player = self.health_Player / (20/13)
        self.attackDMG = 10
        self.speed = 7.5
        self.jumpCount = self.speed
        self.countSteps = 0
        self.go_left = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche4-4.png'))]
        self.go_right = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit4-4.png'))]
        self.rect = [img.get_rect() for img in self.go_left and self.go_right]
        self.rect.x = 25 #The problem is here
        self.rect.y = 640 #The problem is here

    def move_left (self):
        self.rect.x -= self.speed #The problem is here
```

The problem is in the second file, I marked it with #
So what could I do, to localize each pictures of the two lists in two variables : `self.rect.x` and `self.rect.y` ?
Thanks for taking the time to review my issue !

Comment: Your self.rect is being assigned a list of rects from the list comprehention `self.rect = [img.get_rect() for img in self.go_left and self.go_right]`, not an individual rect. A list does not have an `x` or `y` attribute so that gives you the error when you try to access that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a PyGame `Sprite` based on `pygame.sprite.Sprite` the sprite `.image` and `.rect` are the critical components that define where the sprite is, and how it looks.

The `Sprite.image` is a single `pygame.Surface`.

The `Sprite.rect` is a *single* `pygame.Rect`

Your code is assigning a list-of-Rect to `Sprite.rect`, and this will not work.  Most sprite implementations change the image and rect in the sprite `.update()` function, which is called every frame.

So, how to go forward.  First repair the sprite rect:

```
class Player( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    LEFT  = 0       # enumerated direction types
    RIGHT = 1

    def __init__( self, image_path, x, y ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__( self )
        # Load animation
        self.go_left = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatGauche4-4.png'))]
        self.go_right = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit1-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit2-4.png')),pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit3-4.png')), pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, 'Sprite_soldatDroit4-4.png'))]

        self.image      = self.go_left[0]
        self.rect       = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x     = x
        self.rect.y     = y
        self.direction  = self.LEFT  # initially heading left
        self.frame_index= 0          # which animation frame is used
```

This correctly sets the image and rect to the first animation frame, assuming the player starts facing left.

Then when the player moves, cycle through the animation in the correct direction.  The key idea here is that to animate the sprite, the code is simply picking the next image for the direction, and *then* re-positioning the `sprite.rect` to match both the image and the new position.

```
    def move( self, direction, x_delta ):
        # use the next animation index
        if ( direction != self.direction ):   # player turned?
            self.frame_index = 0
        else:
            self.frame_index += 1             # player continued
        self.direction = direction

        if ( direction == Player.LEFT ):
            # loop at the last frame
            self.frame_index %= len( self.go_left )          
            self.image = self.go_left[ self.frame_index ]
        else:  # direction == Player.RIGHT
            self.frame_index %= len( self.go_right )
            self.image = self.go_right[ self.frame_index ]

        # re-create the rect with the current co-ordinates
        x, y = self.rect.center
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x + x_delta, y )
```

In your current code, it looks like you're trying to maintain a list of rects.  But how do you keep their positions updated?  It's not saving you anything, because the image already has the rect.

Also - I'm just guessing this is how your animation should work, maybe it's a time-based animation instead.  So, this is just to illustrate one way of doing it.  Maybe it will give you some ideas to help.